# How can i customize swagger-ui.html url with OpenApi

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

as the title suggests, is there a way to change a swagger url of the type

`localhost:8080/myapp/swagger.ui.html`

into a url

```
localhost:8080/docs
```

I use OpenApi3 and so far in the documentation I don't know how to change the "swagger-ui". Thanks for any possible answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the property `springdoc.swagger-ui.path` in your `application.properties` file.

If you don't have the above file, you can also do it by creating `application.yml` file under `src/main/resources` folder, and copy the below YAML property

```yaml
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /docs
```